# Detect as soon as the input field is populated through barcode scanner

Tags: javascript

I have two input fields `productName` and `quantity`,  `productName` field is getting populated using a barcode scanner(don't have access to code), my requirement is to detect as soon as the value gets populated in `productName`  fields so that I can parse the value and populate the second field `quantity`.

```
<input type="text" id="productName" name="productName">
<input type="text" id="quantity" name="quantity">
```

Since I don't have access to code that scans the barcode and populate the `productName` field, there is one possibility which I think of is repeatedly checking if the field has value or not like below

```
myVar = setInterval(checkValue, 1000);

function checkValue(){
var productName= document.getElementById("productName");
console.log("running");
if (productName && productName.value) {
  document.getElementById("quantity").value=productName.value;
  clearInterval(myVar);
}
}
```

But I am looking for a better approach in vanilla Javascript, is there an alternate solution?

Comment: use the onChange event, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event

Comment: thank you @RobertRocha , it works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `onchange`.

**Example:**

```
const productNameField = document.querySelector('#productName');
const quantityField = document.querySelector('#quantity');

const populateQuantityField = () => {
  quantityField.value = productNameField.value;
}

productNameField.addEventListener('change', populateQuantityField);
```

---

**Further Reading:**

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onchange